# Чем отличаются стандартные пути от не стандартных?

Tags: c#

Часто замечаю что используют пути для поиска по разному, но чем они отличаются ( то есть работают на разные ОС как-то по разному или что)?

В чём разница между

```
string environmentVariable = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("temp");
```

или просто

```
string environmentVariable = Path.GetTempPath();
```

А так же интересуюсь:

Console приложение и WindowsForms от .Net 2.0 работают на всех ОС? : Начиная с XP и заканчивая Win 10?!

Comment: .net 2.0 шел в составе Windows начиная с Vista. На XP его надо доустанавливать вручную

Comment: @PashaPash на XP он шел в составе одного из сервис-паков

Comment: @PavelMayorov вроде бы там был только .net 1.1 в SP2/SP3, и то в вид доп. компонента: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/

Comment: @PashaPash Значит на XP будут проблемы с запуском Winforms приложений?

Comment: @ArteS проблем не будет, но придется обновлять XP до SP2 и доставлять на него .net 2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("temp")` просто вернет значение переменной окружения с именем `temp`

`Path.GetTempPath` вернет первое существующее значение из следующего списка:

1. Путь, указанный в переменной среды TMP.
2. Путь, указанный в переменной среды TEMP.
3. Путь, указанный в переменной среды USERPROFILE.
4. Каталог Windows.

... так что он надежнее и безопаснее, чем вызов `GetEnvironmentVariable("temp")`.

Кстати, [это прямо сказано в MSDN по методу `Path.GetTempPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.path.gettemppath(v=vs.110).aspx)